# Issues with Gatsby Build showing white screen on Netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, netlify

I currently have a project that works completely fine in development mode.

When it came to pushing it live, I found issues with failed builds etc so I've started to go down the path of stripping things back to a bare minimum bit of code.

What I'm left with is a simple component that looks like this

```js
import * as React from "react"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Seo from "../components/seo"

const IndexPage = () => {
    return (
        <Layout pageTitle="Upcoming Occupancy">
            Works
        </Layout>
    )
} 

export const Head = () => (
    <Seo title="Home" />
)

export default IndexPage
```

The Layout component is just another basic component like this too. with a nav / header etc.

Running this with `gatsby clean && gatsby build && gatsby serve` has the site loading completely fine with absolutely no errros or warnings in the console.

When I push this to Netlify however, the build appears to pass fine and when looking at the page it appears to look correct except after a few seconds everything goes white and all I'm left with is

```
<div id="___gatsby"></div>
```

and a few other lines of code.

Does anyone know where to look for this issue?

Also on the `Netlify` version, I can see the following in the logs
Error: Minified React error #130;
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #423;

both pointing at react-dom.production.min.js

I'm completely error-free in the dev version and the local production build version though.